# Backup SRAM for STM32 is wiped between resets

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm writing a (better) hard-fault handler for my STM32f207zg and want to do the following:

1. Have a horrible crash
2. Jump into my (C) fault handler
3. Save various registers (CFSR, HFSR, LR, PC, ...) in the backup SRAM
4. Reset
5. When back in main(), check if the watchdog reset the system
6. Fetch the "crash report" saved in the SRAM
7. Dump it on CAN

1,2,4,5,7 is easy, but I'm having problems with saving/restoring from the SRAM.

The hardfault-handler calls the function **fault_bksram_init()** after filling up the **fault_crash_t** structure with data. It then calls **fault_write_crash()** in order to write the "report" to the SRAM. I can see using my debugger that the data is actually written to the address defined in **BKPSRAM_BASE**; however, after doing a reset using the debugger the memory at **BKPSRAM_BASE** is wiped with **0xff** .
In order words, the data is lost between resets.

I have the correct voltage connected to VBat (the RTC works nicely) but I have never used the backup SRAM before.

Am I missing something in the initialization of the SRAM? Is it something with doing this in a hard-fault handler that I'm missing? Or is the debugger reset that messes up the SRAM?

```
void fault_bksram_init(void) {
    /* Enable PWR clock */
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN;

    /* Enable backup SRAM Clock */
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_BKPSRAMEN;

    /* Disable write protection */
    PWR->CR |= PWR_CR_DBP;

    /* Enable backup regulator */
    PWR->CSR |= PWR_CSR_BRE;

    /* Wait for backup regulator to be ready  */
    while (!(PWR->CSR & (PWR_FLAG_BRR)));
}

void fault_write_crash(fault_crash_t* crash) {
    /* Copy crash to BKSRAM */
    memcpy((void*)BKPSRAM_BASE, (void*)crash, sizeof(fault_crash_t));
}
```

Comment: You do not need to put it to the backup RAM. Normal SRAM will retain its value after the software reset (and even NRST pin reser)

Comment: First, make sure that the backup SRAM retains its contents without any fault handling: write something there, halt, let the watchdog restart the cpu, on watchdog reset check SRAM contents. The fault handling is not relevant until you show that you can ordinarily keep data in the backup SRAM.

Comment: @P__J__ When relying on that, some extra care must be taken though. You need a dedicated RAM segment which is exempt from .data and .bss initialization. Reset it manually from power-on reset, but not from wdog reset.

Comment: Wdog is not clearing The memory

Comment: You have not shown the code that _reads_ the SRAM after restart.  Without that information, I'd guess that you are trying to read the SRAM without first enabling the backup SRAM clock.

Comment: @Clifford you nailed it. When reading it back, the BKSRAM clock was not properly initialized (even though I thought it was). Thanks!

Comment: @turbofish do not edit the solution into the question, rather, post an answer as that is the only way (short of closure) that a question on SO can be resolved.

Comment: @turbofish : For the question to be answerable rather then just a guess, you _do_ need to edit the question to to include the information requested: i.e. _the code that reads the SRAM after restart_.  Confirmation that I hit on the right solution in a _temporary_ comment is not really insufficient; comments are not answers and information relevant to the question should be added to the question not posted as a comment.  SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum - the Q's and A's must be coherent independent of any comments.

Comment: @turbofish : I have posted an answer in any case, but it is necessarily vague.  A more specific answer can be given if you add the required information to your question.  Alternatively post you own answer, but ideally you should fix the question too, so that others can see the problem you have solved.

Answer (score 2):

The backup SRAM is not readable until the BKPSRAM clock is enabled.  If you need to enabling it in the exception handler as you have, then it was not previously enabled and therefore could not have been read.

Comment: This answer is a placeholder; it has been confirmed that the clock was not enabled in a comment; for a coherent Q&A the OP would need to include the start-up read back code in the question since that is where the error is.